# Is there any like function in Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook

My webpage will ask for user permission before perform like action.
If I have the permission, is there any FB API that make the user LIKE my page??
(I mean not the Facebook build-in one, but something in javascript function)

Answer (score 0):

No. You are not allowed to perform a like for a user, as that would easily be abused. You must put a like button in the page and let the user click it.